# Error: ReactGridLayout: ReactGridLayout.children[0].x must be a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, save, children

I'm trying to make a RGL layout where I can add and remove tiles and save the configuration. I need the file to be a function component and not a class component.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

const ReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);
localStorage.setItem("username");
const username = localStorage.getItem('username');

/**
 * This layout demonstrates how to sync multiple responsive layouts to localstorage.
 */
export default class Dash extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.originalLayouts = this.getLayout("layouts") || {lg:[]};
    this.savedLayout = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.originalLayouts));
    this.state = {
      layout: this.savedLayout.lg.map(function(i, key) {
        return {
          i: "",
          x: i * 2,
          y: 0,
          w: 2,
          h: 2
        };
      }
      ),
    };
    this.id = uuid()
    this.onLayoutChange = this.onLayoutChange.bind(this);
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    this.now = this.now.bind(this);
    this.saveLayout = this.saveLayout.bind(this);
    this.getLayout = this.getLayout.bind(this);
    }


    // Function to create element on the Dashboard
    createElement(el, i) {
      const removeStyle = {
        position: "absolute",
        right: "2px",
        top: 0,
        cursor: "pointer"
      };
      return (
        <div key={el.i} data-grid={i}>
          <span
            className="remove"
            style={removeStyle}
            onClick={this.removeItem.bind(this, el.i)}
          >
            x
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    }


    // Function ammends layout array with additional grid item
    addItem = (item) => { 
        const id = uuid();
        console.log('adding: ' + id);
        this.setState({
          // Add a new item. It must have a unique key!
          layout: this.state.layout.concat({
            i: `${id}`,
            x: (this.state.layout.length * 2) % (this.state.cols || 12),
            y: 0, // puts it at the bottom
            w: 2,
            h: 2
          })
        },
      }
    

    // Function to remove grid item on click
    removeItem = (i) => {
        console.log('removing: ' + i);
        this.setState({layout: _.reject(this.state.layout, { i:i }) });   
    }
    


    // Function when the layout change
    onLayoutChange= (layout, layouts) => {
        this.saveLayout("layouts", layouts);
        this.setState({layout: layout});
    }



    // Function to save user layout to LS
    saveLayout = ( key, value ) => {
      if (global.localStorage) {
        global.localStorage.setItem(username, JSON.stringify({ [key]: value}) );
        console.log("Saving Layout...", value);
      }
    };



    // Function to get user layout from LS
    getLayout = (key) => {
      let ls = {};
      if (global.localStorage) {
        try {
          ls = JSON.parse(global.localStorage.getItem(username)) || {};
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error getting layout')
        }
      }
      return ls[key]
    };


    render() {
      return (
        <div id="maincontent" className="content">
          <ReactGridLayout
            className="layout"
            resizeHandles={['se']}
            compactType={"vertical"}
            draggableHandle=".dragHandle"
            onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
            // onBreakpointChange={this.onBreakpointChange}
            {...this.props}
          >
            {_.map(this.state.layout, (elem, i) => this.createElement(elem, i))}
          </ReactGridLayout>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Can you spot where I made a mistake ? I can't find what is the problem. I can start with a blank dashboard, then add an item and it works.
But if I add a second item ! This error is raised.

Thanks !